# Tracking the firstResponder object

Tags: ios, first-responder

I need to keep track of which text field is the firstResponder for my custom keyboard to work.  In the code below, I have grossly oversimplified my program, but here is the gist of the problem:

```
@implementation SimplePickerViewController
@synthesize pickerKeyboard;
@synthesize textView;
@synthesize textView2;
@synthesize firstResponder;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    pickerKeyboard = [[PickerKeyboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PickerKeyboard" bundle:nil];
    pickerKeyboard.delegate = self;
    [self.textView setInputView:pickerKeyboard.view];
    [self.textView setDelegate:self];
    [self.textView2 setInputView:pickerKeyboard.view];
    [self.textView2 setDelegate:self];
}

-(void)hideKeyboard{
    [self.firstResponder resignFirstResponder];
    self.firstResponder = nil; //without this line, the code doesn't work.
}
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    self.firstResponder = textView;
    [self.pickerKeyboard.picker reloadAllComponents];
    return YES;
}
```

If I remove the line setting the firstResponder to nil, the code ceases to function properly, but I am not sure why.  (Without that line, I can select the first textView to bring up the keyboard, but after that I can never bring the keyboard back.  Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that I understand why firstResponder needs to be kept track of for a custom keyboard to work. I use a custom keyboard without knowing what the first responder is.

Do you use:

```
textView.inputView = pickerKeyboard
```

How about the following, called on the view to resign the first responder:

```
[self.view endEditing:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem and I have just figured out the issue.  Somewhere in some part of Apple's first responder code, they are using a selector named `firstResponder`.  When you created the property `firstResponder` you inadvertently overrode that selector.  That will cause Apple's code to fail.  This, in my humble opinion, is a bug in Apple's framework, and the `firstResponder` method isn't documented anywhere.  Name your property `myFirstResponder` or anything else and everything should work just fine.

See [Why does the keyboard not show when a view is popped from the navigation stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141161/why-does-the-keyboard-not-show-when-a-view-is-popped-from-the-navigation-stack/8142841#8142841)